# Make floor pattern

Tags: c++, for-loop

How do i make this?
[image of my homework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzMGj.png)

note: Batasan means limitaion and Contoh means example

So, my professor wants me to do make output the same size horizontal and vertically in pattern shown in the image
I dont know what to do, but the best i can make is this:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int n;
const char * array1[4];
const char * array2[4];
array1[0] = "O", array1[1] = ">", array1[2] = "X", array1[3] = "<";
array2[0] = "v", array2[1] = "/", array2[2] = "^", array2[3] = "\\";
cin>>n;
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    if (i%2 != 0){
        for(int j = 0; j <=n; j++){
            cout << array1[j]; 
        }
        cout<<"\n";
        } else if (i%2 != 0) {
        for(int j = 0; j <=n; j++){
            cout << array2[j]; 
        }
        cout<<"\n";
}

return 0;
}
}
```

I dont know if array is necessary or not.

If you guys have any suggestion about my program feel free to give me some.

This is my first time asking in this web and im sorry if my post and english are terrible

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: First of all, on SO you should always write out questions fully, with everything being contained in the question itself. That is no using links if avoidable, and writing what is not working.

Comment: Aside from that, take a look at your line `cout << array1[j];`. If j gets bigger than your array size, what is supposed to happen? Would be an invalid access, right? So, what could you do with that line to make it right? (I am hesitant giving you the solution directly, as, after all, this is supposed to be an exercise for you.)

Comment: (Other than that, I'd recommend that you stop using `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`, and that you use `std::vector` or `std::array` instead of raw arrays. Also, consider creating a function `void paint_floor_pattern(int n)` instead of putting all the code in your `main`.)

Comment: @Aziuth Thank you for your suggestions. I'm new at learning C++ and my professor hasn't teach me that yet, so i don't know that is a thing. I will try my best to improve in C++ and also using this website. I'm sorry for my bad post (and my english of course) Have a nice day :))

Answer (score 0):

We are here to help.

I will first show you the problems in your code and then make a proposal on how to make it better.

So, let us first check your code:

- `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` is a non C++ compliant compiler extension. It should never be used. On my machine, it does not compile.
- `using namespace std;` should not be used. It is better to always use full qualified names. This will avoid name clashes from different scopes or namespaces
- Variables should have meaningful names. One character variables are in most cases not that good
- All variables should be initialized during definition
- C-Style arrays should not be used in C++. Always use a specialized STL container like `std::vector` or `std::array`
- In C++ we use `std::string` for strings and not `char[]` or `char *`
- Array indices in C/C++ start with 0. If you use `<=` in the end condition of a `for` loop, you will access an element one past the end. This is a severe out of bound error. You do that in you for loop with the 'j'
- There is anyway a severe out of bound bug here. You access `array[j]` and j might be 4 or bigger. That is a bug and must be corrected. You can simply do a modulo devision `%` by 4. Then you do never exceed the 4. it will then always be `0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3 . .` .
- You should write as much as possible comments

If we correct all this findings, then we could come up with:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

constexpr size_t NumberOfLinePatterns = 2;
constexpr size_t NumberOfElementsPerLinePattern = 4;

using Pattern = std::array<std::array<char, NumberOfElementsPerLinePattern>, NumberOfLinePatterns>;

// If you do not yet know the std::array. Then uncomment the following and 
// remove on opening and closing curly brace in the initialization below
// using Pattern = char[NumberOfLinePatterns][NumberOfElementsPerLinePattern];

Pattern pattern{{
    {'O','>','X','<'},
    {'v','/','^','\\'}
 }};

int main() {

    // Get number of rows and columns to print
    unsigned int numberOfElements{}; std::cin >> numberOfElements;

    // Now, for all rows and columns
    for (unsigned int row{}; row < numberOfElements; ++row) {
        for (unsigned int column{}; column < numberOfElements; ++column) {

            // Print the selected character
            std::cout << pattern[row % NumberOfLinePatterns][column % NumberOfElementsPerLinePattern];
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```